# Is there a way to derive a type argument from a string for passing into a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I typed this out in Notepad++ real quick so please forgive any typos/mistakes. If it's possible, I'd be getting rid of some repetitive work (i.e. a long case statement). Not a huge deal but I'm curious if it's possible and if so, how bad would it be to actually implement the code.

```
jsonFromWebpage = {
    StatusUpdate: {
        QueryType: "SomeClassName",
        LocalCount: 5,
        RemoteCount: 5
    },
    StatusUpdate: {
        QueryType: "AnotherClass",
        LocalCount: 29,
        RemoteCount: 30
    }
}

// Model
public class StatusUpdate
{
    public string QueryType { get; set; }
    public int LocalCount { get; set; }
    public int RemoteCount { get; set; }
}

// Controller
public IActionResult GetStatusUpdate([FromBody] List<StatusUpdate> status)
{
    _service.GetStatusUpdate(status);
    return status
}

// Service
public List<Status> GetStatusUpdate(List<StatusUpdate> status)
{
    foreach(var s in status)
    {
        var typeArgument = s.QueryType; // <--- Is there a way for this...
        status.CurrentCount = GetTotalCount<typeArgument>(); // <--- to work here?
        status.RemoteCount = thisworksfineforotherreasons(s.QueryType);
    }
}

// Repo
public int GetTotalCount<T>() where T: class
{
    var result = _db.GetCount<T>();
    return result;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

First, thank you to everyone that has responded. Having read everything so far, I wanted to give a little more context. Here's a different take on the example:

```
// View
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="api-types">History</div>
    <div class="progress-bar">50 out of 50 copied</div>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="api-types">Users</div>
    <div class="progress-bar">25 out of 32 copied</div>
</div>

// -- View javascript

var types = [];
$(".api-types").each(function (c, i) {
    types.push({ ApiAndClassName: $(i).text() });
});

pushToController(JSON.stringify(types));

// Controller
public IActionResult GetSyncStatus(List<SyncStatusVM> status)
{
    _service.GetSyncStatus(status);
    return Json(status);
}

// Service
public List<SyncStatusVM> GetSyncStatus(List<SyncStatusVM> status)
{
    foreach(var s in status)
    {
        // LocalCount
        var magicTypeFigurator = s.ApiAndClassName
        s.LocalCount = _repo.GetCount<magicTypeFigurator>(); <-- "this is a variable but should be a type..."

        // Remote
        var url = $"https://api.domain.com/{s.ApiAndClassName.ToLower()}"
        s.RemoteCount = FetchCountFromApi(url);
    }
    return status;
}

// Repository
public long GetCount<T>()
{
    var result = _orm.Count<T>();
    return result;
}

// Models
public class SyncStatusVM
{
    public string ApiAndClassName { get; set; }
    public int LocalCount { get; set; }
    public int RemoteCount { get; set; }
}

public class History
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
}

public class Users
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

Using this code, I can just create a  section in the view and a class for each type. The class is reused by the ORM and desearializing from the API. The most cumbersome point is having a case statement in the controller that calls the generic method with the correct type, based on the "ApiAndClassName". I could edit the ORM so it's string based instead of generic but I don't like that method for various reasons. I could turn the case statement into a collection in the controller or just move it to the service layer but what I have in place already works. I could also just refactor so the view builds from a collection but there are other data points where that wouldn't be the best option. Unless there's something I'm missing, the generic argument from string thing kinda makes sense. It's a fringe case... and kinda just curious if it can be done well enough.

Comment: I assume that `s.QueryType` should actually be `s.ClassName`?

Comment: You can use [Assembly.GetType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype?view=netframework-4.8) and pass the result to [MakeGenericType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Generic types must resolve at **compile time**. If it's in a string variable, you don't know about it until **run time** :( This is a solvable issue, but a generic method isn't going to be your best option.

Comment: Why not simply use a class, tupple or struct that has 1 String and 2 Int Fields? If JSON gives you a collection of something - much less things that are so similar looking - usually those things are of the same underlying type. Or at least a very shallow class heirarchy. And you can easily do any filtering you will need based on the string, as much as you could on the class.

Answer (score 1):

Generally strong typsisation is your friend. Compile time type checks are a feature, not a enemy to be fought. Without them or with too agressive casting, we get the JavaScript and PHP examples from [this comic](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/).

For work with weakly typed langauges or WebServices, .NET has the ExpandoObject. The data can be stored in it, then later transfered into the proper type of instance. Also it looks like your case would fall into JSON deserialisation, wich is a well established code.

Generic is the wrong term. Generics are usually about the type still being known at compile time, so the compile time type checks still work. You are explicitly about the type not being known at compile time, only at runtime. This is very distinct from a generic. Dynamic Types are the proper term afaik. But to not mix it up with the type Dynamic (yes, naming here becomes really confusing).

[Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) is the droid you are looking for. For most purposes, the name of a class or field does not exist at runtime. It is primarily there for you and the compiler to communicate. Now Reflection is the exception. It is all about getting stuff (like instances or property/fields) based on a string representation of their name. The nessesary metadata is baked into the .NET Assemblies, as much as the COM support. But as I support strong typisation, I am not a friend of it.

switch/case statements can usually be replaced with a collection of some sort. Cases are really just a hardcoded way to check a collection of constants. You use the case identifier as the key and whatever else you need for the Value. You can totally use Functions as the value (thanks to delegates). Or the [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type) type, you then use for the instance creation.

But for your case it sounds like all of this is wrong. Bog standart Inheritance - Inheritance might be the *real* droid you are looking for. A JSON service would not usually give you different instance in a single collection, *unless* those instances are related in some way. "SomeClassName" and "AnotherClass" should have another ancestor. Or in fact, they should even **be** just one class - QueryType is simply a string field of said class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a way to map strings to `Type` objects, yes: you can use [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-3.5):

```
var totalCount = (int) (
    GetType()
    .GetMethod("GetTotalCount")
    .MakeGenericMethod(MapStringToType(s.QueryType))
    .Invoke(this, null)
);
```

This assumes the presence of a method `Type MapStringToType(string)` in the local scope.

One way to map types would be to use a `Dictionary<string, Type>` and fill it with the allowed types and their respective names that will be used in the JSON data to refer to them.